# authenticating using a token in react

Tags: rest, authentication, reactjs

I am trying to GET some RESTful services using the api located at https://api.mmitnetwork.com

If I make a GET request it gives me a 401 error Unathorized. In order to authenticate using their api I am suppose to make a POST to https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token with

{"grant_type":"password", "username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}

in the body get a token.

How would I do this in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

```
axios.post(' https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token', {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: 'yourusername',
    password: 'yourpassword',
}).then((response) => {
    console.log('success!')
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log('something went wrong :(')
})
```